# How do I redirect stdout in blessed?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

Long story short: I want to build a CLI for a development daemon. Daemon outputs different kind of information to stdout and I want to relay that information to user in an area of screen, in scrollable fashion.
I am struggling with getting stdout to blessed. Simple prototype below, which buffers stdout, so information is never complete.

```
var blessed = require('blessed');

var screen = blessed.screen(),
body = blessed.box({
  top: 1,
  left: 0,
  width: '100%',
  height: '99%'
}),
statusbar = blessed.box({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: '100%',
  height: 1,
  style: {
    fg: 'white',
    bg: 'blue'
  }
});

screen.append(statusbar);
screen.append(body);

screen.key(['escape', 'q', 'C-c'], function(ch, key) {
  return process.exit(0);
});

function status(text) { statusbar.setContent(text); screen.render(); }
function log(text) { body.insertLine(0, text); screen.render(); }

status('TEST');

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

yes = spawn('yes', ['it is']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   log(data.toString());
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: What is `ls` in your example code? Maybe I am missing something, but all you need to do to get `stdout` form your spawned `yes` process is listen for the 'data' event from `yes.stdout`...

Comment: I need to run multiple commands after another, so "yes" = /bin/yes and "ls" = /bin/ls only I'm using node analogue, I don't spawn a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var screen = blessed.screen()
```

Takes parameters in order to change where the input comes from, and where the output goes too.  Logically, they're named input and output:

```
var screen = blessed.screen({ input: some_input_stream, output: some_output_stream })
```

So, you just chuck a writeable (or duplex) stream into the output parameter.  Then, you can pipe the output anywhere you wish.